# How can I use a Predicate in Java?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

How can I use the following Predicate?

```
Predicate<Integer> isOdd = n -> n % 2 != 0;
```

My try:

```
System.out.println(isOdd(5));
```

Compiler output:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method isOdd(int)
location: class Main
```

Comment: `Predicate` is an interface, so it is used as such. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html). But actually it is intended to be used as a functional interface, involving lambda expressions (or Java 8 Streams)

Comment: (in short: `isOdd` is just a normal variable referencing a *normal* instance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To invoke a `Predicate`, use the method called `test`.

```
System.out.println(isOdd.test(5));
```

or

```
if(isOdd.test(5)){
  // Do something fun
}
```

This is [documented here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

Answer (score 2):

`Predicate<T>` is an interface, so you need to explicitly call the method declared in it, i.e. `test(T t)`; even if the variable captured a lambda:

```
isOdd.test(5)
```